# Finding the inverse of $H-G E^{-1}F$

Tags: matrices

What's the inverse of $H-G E^{-1}F$ where $H$ is an invertible matrix?

Is there a systematic way to find it or should I play with the expression until I get lucky?

edit: Maybe there's no way and I'll just have to write $(H-G E^{-1}F)^{-1}$. But can we be sure it's invertible?

Comment: I don't think in general $H-G E^{-1}F$ is invertible. Think about $H=G=F=E=I$.

Comment: Maybe this is related: when $A$,$D$ are both invertible, $$|A||D-CA^{-1}B|=|D||A-BD^{-1}C|.$$

Comment: @Vim $M/E = H-G E^{-1}F$ appears in the "partitioned inverse formula" which gives the inverse of a partitioned matrix, so I thought it was always invertible and I didn't even look for easy counterexamples. The theorem just says "assume $E$ and $H$ are invertible".